# Is there a jQuery plugin for help balloons for first time users of a site?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, wizard

Something like "Click here to get started" or whatnot. I am planning to add a "tutorial" mode for a site and was wondering if there was a jquery or rails plugin for it already.

I have tried googling for tool tips but all i get are hover(or click) activated ones. You usually see these tool tips for flash games with tutorials(just an example), but is it possible with jquery?

Comment: If you dig deeper in the plugins you'll find that many of them allow you to trigger tooltips manually. qTip2 certainly lets you do that.

Comment: Why the hell is this question closed? It is constructive and it gives valueable information. Stop whining about the exact rules so hard.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this, it is awesome !

- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/

and the demo :

- http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/

Comment: Wow that was cool and fast! Thanks!